# "ionic cordova build android" command excution giving error

Tags: node.js, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework

"ionic cordova build android" command excution giving error

[Error while excuting command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yBDc.png)

Comment: can you share your ionic info

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining that **npm** is not recognized, check for the node version that you are using. if it's not there install form here https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: It's alreay there.